# How to write a function to change the value of a variable in the main scope in Ruby

Tags: ruby, scope

I have a assigment to write a value swap function in c, I don't know how to do it in ruby either

in Ruby something like

```
a = 1

b = 2

value_swap!(a,b)

puts a #=> 2

puts b #=> 1
```

The difficulty here is how to use a function to change the value in the main scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby strings are mutable, so you can have:

```
a= "43"
b= "42"

def wtf!(a, b)
    t= a.clone
    a.gsub!(a, b)
    b.gsub!(b, t)
end

wtf!(a, b)

puts a, b
```

Unfortunately, Fixnum is not mutable, so self= n will not work.

**Edit: Another example of mutable data structures**

Here's another mutable data structure, the array. This might clarify my answer.

```
a= [43]
b= [42]

def omg!(a, b)
    b[0], a[0]= a[0], b[0]
end

omg!(a, b)

p a, b
```

Comment: here's an interesting find http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/2710

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. but not quite get yet. does gsub use binding such thing to achieve this

Comment: gsub! modifies the string memory in-place. Classes like Fixnum and Float don't have this ability. That is what I mean by mutable strings.

Answer (score 2):

It's a major hack, but you can try something like this:

```
def value_swap(a,b,parent_binding)
    parent_binding.eval("#{a},#{b}=#{b},#{a}")
end

a=1
b=2
value_swap :a,:b,binding
puts a
puts b
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution

Comment: In addition to  what Idan Arye said -> http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/RubyBindings.rdoc

Comment: @yozloy More elegant solution to what problem? For the problem of swapping two primitives there is an elegant solution, Kai Konig already gave you a solution: `a,b=b,a`. For the problem of **writing a function** that swaps two variables, I don't think there is an elegant solution in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby supports the parallel assignment of variables which comes in handy if you would like to swap the *values* of the variables like so:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = 1
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> b = 2
=> 2
irb(main):003:0> a,b = b,a
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):004:0> a
=> 2
irb(main):005:0> b
=> 1
irb(main):006:0>
```

But i guess that does not really help with the assignment. In C you would act on references e.g. passing the pointers of those variables to the function and then manipulate them.

If you can't come up with a solution, here is an attempt ( not mine ):

```
void swap(int *i, int *j) {
   int t = *i;
   *i = *j;
   *j = t;
}

void main() {
   int a = 23, b = 47;
   printf("Before. a: %d, b: %d\n", a, b);
   swap(&a, &b);
   printf("After . a: %d, b: %d\n", a, b);
}
```

Comment: `void swap_2(char a,char b){
  int t;
  t = a;
  a = b;
  b = t; 
} ` why this code doesn't work?

Comment: @yozloy Arguments in C are always passed by value. That means that when you write `int a=1,b=2; swap_2(a,b)`, you don't pass `a` and `b` to `swap_2` - you pass their values, `1` and `2`. `a` and `b` in the function have nothing to do with `a` and `b` outside the function - if you change the variables inside the function, that does not affect the variables outside the function. The C solution for this is called *pass by address* - you don't pass the value of the variable, you pass a pointer to it. The pointer is passed by value, but since it's a pointer, you can use it to alter the variable.

Comment: @IdanArye Thanks for your great explaination. totally makes sense to me. how powerfull c is!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's semantics don't, unless you use trickery, permit what you're trying to do.

For the example you gave, I'd just use parallel assignment, which uses no trickery and will be immediately obvious to the reader of your code:

```
a, b = b, a
```